# Which filters will fit Voigtlander 15mm?

Tags: lens, filters, voigtlander

I recently got myself Voigtlander Super Wide-Heliar 15mm/4.5 lens, which I enjoy shooting a lot. It has built-in lens hood with filter threads and manual says it's fitted with 52mm filter threads.

I want to use it with ND filter and when I got to the store I wasn't able to screw in a single filter because filter body seem to be too "wide" and diameter of the hood too narrow. I've also tried step-down rings and I had exactly the same problem, as rings were hitting the hood.

Should I looks for some kind of special filters to fit this lens?

Lens photo for the reference (you can see threads inside the hood):

[image: Voigtlander Super Wide-Heliar 15mm/4.5]

Comment: They are notoriously hard to fit filters to, unfortunately.

Comment: What camera are you putting this on? Someone [on dpreview said they use a step-*down* 52->46 ring](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/50335477) on NEX; since the sensor's APS-C, the vignetting doesn't show.

Comment: @inkista Sony A7 it's FF sensor and this lens vignettes pretty bad already.

Comment: 'fraid that was it. Maybe it's time to contemplate the FE 16-35/4 ZA instead?

Comment: @inkista if only it'll perform better than 24-70/4. Honestly, I'm so disappointed with lens lineup made by sony, it was a year since camera release and they still didn't covered most of the focal lengths with a good glass.

Comment: Sony's an electronics company; they've been slow with glass on both the A and E mounts. But the 16-35 is a ZA/Zeiss lens, so there's hope. When it arrives. [sigh].

Answer (score 1):

Ken Rockwell talks a bit about your threading issue [here](http://www.kenrockwell.com/voigtlander/15mm-m.htm).

He seems to think this is the standard 52mm thread, which Canon/Nikon fans would be familiar with, but Leica fans would think was quite unique.

Ken is usually right about these things.

Comment: It's 52mm thread indeed, but very few filters seem to be able to fit it because hood is so narrow. I still struggle to find ND filter which will fit.

Comment: Ah, an ND filter. I thought you just wanted a UV Have filter (protective filter). That may not be possible with the hood, yeah. It is a wonderful lens, but that will be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Bombo100v15 holder](http://bombophoto.com/shop/bombo-filters-holder-size-100mm-cokin-z/bombo100v15/), which can fit all filters of size 100mm (Cokin Z).

Please visit here for solution: Holder for all Voigtlander version II & III using filter 100mm :
http://bombophoto.com/shop/bombo-holder/bombo-holder-100mm/av15-iii/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adapter AV15-III or AV15-II for Voigtlander 15mm f4, it fit on Bombo holder name Laser100

Comment: You already posted this answer substantially, last year on May 28. If you have additional information, or more specific information, please edit your previous answer